# Что вызывает ошибку net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, cors

> **ДРУЗЬЯ!**
>   Нужна помощь. Не могу определить, что вызывает ошибку **net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**.
>   Бакенд и фронтенд приложения работают норм, за исключением того, что касается запросов/CORS.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Код на хост развернул, согласно [этой статьи](https://grokonez.com/node-js/vue-js-node-js-express-restapis-mongoose-orm-mongodb-crud-example). Естественно, обновил все пакеты до вывода на продакшн.
>   На хосте *(**VPS**: **CentOS7**, **VestaCP**)* установлена ***nginx*** + ***php-fpm***, а так же ***MongoDB***, ***node.js***, ***@vue/cli***. Все нужные порты открыты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Серверная и клиентская части находятся в одном каталоге/на одном домене. Вот структура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Все зависимости для работы пакетов учтены. Компиляция продакшна и запуска сервера стабильна и без ошибок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Что самое интересное, запросы в браузерах режутся, а через **Postman** прекрасно получаю/отправляю/обновляю данные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

+++**Код server.js**+++

```js
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Parse requests
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Load CORS
const cors = require('cors');
const corsOptions = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',  // сменил на http://<имя моего домена>
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type'],
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Configuring the database
const dbConfig = require('./app/config/mongodb.config.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// Connecting to the database
mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB.");
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('Could not connect to MongoDB.');
    process.exit();
  });

require('./app/routes/customer.routes.js')(app);

// Create a Server
let server = app.listen(dbConfig.serverport, () => {

  let host = server.address().address;
  let port = server.address().port;

  console.log("App listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});
```

+++**Код mongodb.config.js**+++

```js
module.exports = {
  url: 'mongodb://<имя юзера>:<пароль>@localhost:27017/<имя бд>',
  serverport: 8080   // сменил на свободный порт 8081
};
```

+++**Код http-common.js**+++

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api",  // сменил на свободный порт 8081
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
  }
});
```

Жду ваших предположений или может даже **РЕШЕНИЕ**.

Comment: Так localhost или не localhost? Постманом вы видимо зодите в другой сервер, раз закрасили адрес

Comment: А ошибка это сетевая, так что разбираться надо запущено ли у вас вообще приложение на нужном сервере и нужном порту и пропускает ли запросы файрволл (хотя localhost вроде никогда не ограничивают)

Comment: Да, мой косяк был, клиентом долбился на localhost.. частично проблема решена.
Подправил... 
Теперь клиент может только получать из БД, остальные запросы на изменение, удаление и поиск вызывают ошибку CORS.

Comment: Постман и браузер в данном случае это две большие разницы. Когда вы шлете постманом, у вас нет ограничений на ajax запрос, по сути запрос с постмана не является тем, что принято называть ajax запросом.

 Когда же вы шлете браузером, браузер накладывает на запрос ряд ограничений и они, вроде бы, должны решаться проставлением заголовков, которые и проставляются в server.js , однако обратите внимание что если вы шлете ajax c домена отличного от домена, где живет бекенд, то у вас с большой долей вероятности происходит два запроса, первй из них OPTIONS, а уже второй POST, GET, что угодно.

Comment: ... не исключено что то проблема именно в этом. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B

Comment: Я такую ошибку поборол ключами SSL. Сейчас все на HTTPS, но вижу у вас еще HTTP//<мой домен>

Answer (score 3):

### Ошибка найдена. Решилось всё:

- заменой опции origin на сервере *(CORS)*: с **localhost:4200** на
  **http://<мой домен>**.
- перенастройкой портов: прослушиваемый порт **8080** был открыт, но занят другим процессом. Установил другой порт для прослушивания на сервере и повторил его на клиенте.

Все заработало. Всем спасибо!..